# Remove a string from a URL between AND after two different characters using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file which contains a list of URLs enclosed in double quotes:

```
"http://test.com/secure/test/12345/doc.pdf"
```

So I'm trying to append the URL to a file protocol, and also to remove the file name at the end of the URL.
Expected output would be:

```
"file://12345"
```

On mac, I've tried

```
sed -i '.bak' 's~http://test.com/secure/test/~file://~g' url.txt
```

The command above only appended the front part,

`"file://12345/doc.pdf"`

I am not too sure how do I match the first `"http://test.com/secure/test/` and then how to match the next forward slash in the URL `/doc.pdf"`, to remove the file names (which vary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just adapt the following `sed` command to modify your file after confirming that it does work for you:

```
echo '"http://test.com/secure/test/12345/doc.pdf"' | sed -E 's@"http://test.com/secure/test/([^/"]*)/.*"@"file://\1"@'
"file://12345"
```

**Explanations**:

- `([^/"]+)` will capture the `12345` part of your URL (you might have to restrict to a more specific class `[0-9a-zA-Z]` instead of `[^/"]`
- `/.*"` will match the `/` and the rest of the URL

Comment: `'s@.*([^/]*)/.*"@"file://\1@'` would be briefer and uncouple the code from the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk -F/ '{print "\"file://" $(NF-1)"\"" }' urlfile.txt
```

**explanation**

```
-F/                # fieldseperator is /
'{print "\"file://"  # print fix part
$(NF-1)"\"" }'         # print penultimate field
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it shorter way to do it in `awk`! +1

Comment: However note that `awk -F/ '{print "\"file://" $(NF-1)"\"" }'` might be better if we need to keep the URLs into `"` anyway +1

Comment: I have edited your answer, to fix the explanation part as well